# Applying Multiple materials in Unity particle system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, render, particles

I am trying to apply multiple materials to a mesh renderer in my particle system but I cannot figure out how to do so.

I have provided a link to 4 images, the first 2 are an example of the particle system in action and the final two are what I am trying to accomplish. I am rendering the same mesh object but am only given the option for 1 material.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZcQR.jpg

Comment: First, it's best to phrase this as a question. What are you asking the community? Second, embed an image rather than posting a link.

Answer (score 1):

Use Particles Texture Sheet Animation https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/particles-texture-sheet-animation

> A Texture Sheet is a series of images inside one Texture file that can be played on a particle in the Particle System. In the Particle System, you can use the Texture Sheet Animation module to set a Texture Sheet’s parameters. Some artists put all their VFX Textures into one image called a Texture Atlas to optimize performance and then use the Texture Sheet Animation module to select which image the Particle System uses.
>
> When creating a sparkle effect, it’s nice to have some visual variety.
> Instead of copying the emitter four times and assigning a different
> Material to each emitter, we’ll use a Texture Sheet animation to set
> up a 2 x 2 Texture that randomly selects one of the Texture’s four
> stars.
>
> 1. Create a Texture Sheet with four unique star images evenly spaced in a square. You can use guides to make sure the stars are centered
>    (Figure 01).
> 2. Import the Texture into Unity.
> 3. Create a Material for the Texture.
> 4. Create a new Particle System and assign the Material to it. You will see all four stars displayed on each particle.
> 5. Enable the check box to the left of Texture Sheet Animation and set Tiles X and Y to 2  (Figure 02).
> 6. Change the Frame over Time setting by selecting the arrow on the right. Select Constant and set it to 0. This means the particle will
>    use the same image for its lifetime.
> 7. Select the drop-down arrow to the right of Start Frame and select Random Between Two Constants. Set the first frame to 0 and the second
>    frame to 4. (Unity will automatically change it to 3.9996.) This tells
>    the Particle System to randomly select between the four star images.
>    Once this is set, you should see all four images randomly appearing on
>    the particles being spawned.

Comment: I am so happy you quoted the article, now that the link is dead.